# creating a simple encryption and decryption based on 1 value

Tags: c#, algorithm, encryption, cryptography

How to make a c# algorithm that takes an int value and hashes it into a combination of 8 digits, letters and signs return it and then decrypt it and given the hash will return the original value?

Example:

Input - 15896
Output - A7Bg82!0

Input - A7Bg82!0
Output - 15896

Comment: Mmmh. Is your question: "How to code a cipher / decipher algo" ?

Comment: Yes, sorry my bad!

Comment: Unless you want to use c# crypto libraries, the answer is pretty difficult. You should read a crypto course I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is a secret... Haha

Necklondon commented that this sounds more like a cipher / decipher situation.

```
    public string cipher(string s)
    {
        var array = s.ToCharArray();
        string secret = "asow4akec13";
        int secretLength = secret.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] += secret.ElementAt(i % secretLength);
        }
        return array.ToString();
    }
    
    public string deCipher(string s)
    {
        var array = s.ToCharArray();
        string secret = "asow4akec13";
        int secretLength = secret.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] -= secret.ElementAt(i % secretLength);
        }
        return array.ToString();
    }
```

Warning this is not encrypted!!  If you're doing this for fun/school than this is an ok solution.

It's also a very superficial way of ciphering.  For proper encoding we need to scramble the string using much more complicated algorithms and using multiple secrets that can't so easily be reverse engineered.

But I think this can help you as a basic example.

If you really want to encrypt something don't reinvent the wheel, use a crypto library.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Check if the input starts with !"!" or not

2- if not :

```
Salt=random number lower than 1000000
return '!'+strtobase64(sha256(iint(nput)*1000000+salt)
```

3- if it does

```
return int(base64tostr(input less "!"))/1000000
```

Use google to find base64 and sha256 algorithm. The latter might be a bit complex but it is what you need if you wany a strong cyphering.

The salt is there to make it harder to guess a specific cypher because the same input will turn into several different cyphers. Remove this part if it is not needed in your use case.